# Problem with Listings package concerning line breaking and wrong alignment

Tags: listings

[image]Hello I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.5in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,title={Blinking both LEDs},breaklines=true]

#include  <msp430g2553.h>

 unsigned int i = 0;

void main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;

  P1DIR |= 0x01;
  P1DIR |= 0x40;

  for(;;)

  {
        //Both LEDs blink simultaneously

        P1OUT ^= 0x01;
        P1OUT ^= 0x40;

        //Or alternative P1OUT ^= 0x01|0x40

        for(i=0;i<30000;i++);

        //If I place P1OUT ^= 0x40; here then one LED blink and then the other
  };

}


\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

In the last comment why doesn't the new line starts from the beggining (meaning under the //) but instead starts with a little left margin? And also why the first comment is far more left than the rest of the code in its block?

I have uploaded an image also with tabs on. There is something wrong. When I experiment with tabs odd things happen and the document doesn't appear as it should be. The second image is based on the code I wrote in that post and I haven't experiment on that one.

[image]

Comment: You must have a `tab`, versus actual spaces which are being treated differently.  You can try adjusting `tabsize=<number>`.  Cutting and pasting your MWE works fine for me so the tabbing must be getting lost in the pasting here.

Comment: @PeterGrill The site replaces all tabs by 4 spaces.

Comment: For debugging this you could add `showtabs=true` to your listing

Comment: There is something wrong...Even though I press tab in the first comment it doesn't appear...

Comment: @Adam Try to copy the code you posted in your question, paste it back into your editor/IDE, and compile. Do you get the same output?

Comment: Hm no I don't! Everything appers as it should. Weird...

Comment: @Adam The reason is probably that given by Peter Grill in his earlier comment, then: your editor must insert a tab character when you hit the Tab key. In my experience, when using `listings`, it's safer to stick to spaces instead. Most editors/IDEs can be configured to insert spaces (e.g. 4) instead of a tab character when the Tab key is pressed. Look into it.

Comment: This problem you mean is fault of the LaTeX editor or the editor in which I wrote the program in C?

Comment: @Adam Well, if you only use "embedded" listings (by using an `lstlisting` environment, as in your MWE) as opposed to "standalone" listings (by using `\lstinputlisting`), the problem can be solved in your LaTeX editor alone.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the last comment but thank you anyway!

Comment: @Adam What I mean is that, if your document only uses `lstlisting` (not `\lstinputlisting`), you can solve the problem completely in your LaTeX editor by searching for tab characters and replacing each of them by an appropriate number of spaces (typically, 2 or 4).